# How to move multiple IPs to different lines

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have a program that lists hostnames and IPs. Some hostnames have multiple IPs assigned to them. When I download the IP column .csv, it lists as such:

```
192.168.xx.xx
"192.168.xx.xx, 192.168.xx.xx"
192.168.xx.xx
```

I am putting the contents of this .csv file into a VI file. What I would like to do is figure out how to script it so that the lines with 2 IPs (with the " " and ,) move one of the IPs to a new line and remove all of the " "  and , so that I can easily run this through a Powershell script to ping each and get their up/down status.

Goal would be to get this file:

```
192.xx.xx
192.xx.xx
192.xx.xx
192.xx.xx
```

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Are those meant to be on separate lines?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:substitute` command for this:

```
:%s/"//g | %s/, /\r/g
```

First replace all quotation marks with nothing (I assume there will be no escaped `"`s since these are just IP addresses). Then (`|` is the command separator) replace all `', '` with linebreaks (`\r`).

References:

- [`:help :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute)
- [`:help range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange)
- [`:help pattern`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern)

Comment: After @TommyA's edit I would recommend changing substitution to `:%s/"\(.*\),\(.*\)"/\1\r\2/g`

Comment: @Tumbler41 That's assuming that there's only two IPs in each field.  If this was a common thing that needs to be done I would make a command with: `%s/^"\(.*\)"/\=substitute(submatch(1), ',\s*', "\r", 'g')/g` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Those are both more complicated ways of achieving the same result.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I read your expression wrong. Yeah, yours is fine.

Comment: Well, if you need performance, one command is probably faster. I guess I just prefer to keep things simple if possible.

Comment: @Antony They definitely are a bit much to type into the command line if this was a one time occurrence. In that case, I would most likely do two substitutions like in your answer. If this is a semi-regular task, where I'm parsing somewhat large log files, I'd go with what I mentioned above to do a single sweep of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use macros to do the same thing.

For removing `"`,  do this.

```
qaqqa/"<CR>xn@aq
```

For removing `,` and replacing it with a new line,

```
qsqqs/,<CR>i<CR>xx@sq
```

Now, explanation:

```
qa - start recording a  macro and stores in register `a`
q - stops the macro (empties register content.
/" - find double quotes
<CR> - enter. Don't type <CR> but press enter instead of this.
x - delete the current character
n - find next occurrence
@a - replay the macro recursively
q stop the macro.
```

You can execute the macros by pressing `@a` and `@s` in normal mode.